# Collapse from react-bootsrap doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to use [Collapse from react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/utilities/transitions/) to create a collapsible table row.

I want to create table rows that expand and collapse on click, so I can show more information about that specific row.

On the react-bootstrap page it seems to work, but when I duplicate it to work with a  instead of a  it stops working. This is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Collapse from 'react-bootstrap/Collapse';
import Table from "react-bootstrap/Table";

function OppTable (props) {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    return (
      <>
      <Table
      striped bordered hover
      onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
      aria-controls="example-collapse-text"
      aria-expanded={open}>

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>Last visited</th>
                <th>Visits</th>
                <th>FTE</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        {
            props.opportunities.map(opportunity => {
                return (
                    <>      
                        <tr onClick={() => setOpen(!open)} aria-controls="example-collapse-text" aria-expanded={open}>
                            <td>{opportunity.companyname}</td>
                            <td>{opportunity.city}</td>
                            <td>{opportunity.lastVisit}</td>
                            <td>{opportunity.totalVisits}</td>
                            <td>{opportunity.employees}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <Collapse>
                            <tr id="example-collapse-text">
                                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus
                                terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer
                                labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
                            </tr>
                        </Collapse>
                    </>
                )

            })
        }
        </tbody>
      </Table>
      </>
    );
  }

export default OppTable;
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you provide a working reproduction in a Codepen/CodeSandbox?

Comment: properly use table!, enclose close with second <tr><Collapse/></tr>

Comment: cover all tr with table

Comment: Can you please also share from where you are passing props to `Table`?

Comment: Can you please do what @sathishkumar suggested?

Answer (score 0):

**Missing an import statement for Table, you are using a table, but you did not import a table from the  react-bootstrap**

> import Table from "react-bootstrap/Table";

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Collapse from 'react-bootstrap/Collapse';
// import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Table from "react-bootstrap/Table";

function Example() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
      <div>
          <Table
              striped bordered hover
              onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
              aria-controls="example-collapse-text"
              aria-expanded={open}
          >
            <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>First Name</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>Mark</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>Jacob</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>3</td>
              <td colSpan="2">Larry the Bird</td>

            </tr>
            </tbody>
          </Table>

        <Collapse in={open}>
          <div id="example-collapse-text">
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus
            terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer
            labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
          </div>
        </Collapse>
      </div>
  );
}

export default Example;
```

Comment: I've edited the code in the question with what I have. But the collapse still doesn't work.